# Has a flight data recorder or cockpit voice recorder ever failed in an accident?

Tags: accidents, flight-data-recorder, cockpit-voice-recorder, failures

Has there been a time either during an aviation accident or during normal flight where the flight data recorder or the cockpit voice recorder devices failed or the data was significantly corrupted?

Comment: There are a number of incidents recorded where the FDR was destroyed or unreadable, most being due to post-accident fires.  Wiki have the following list; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unrecovered_flight_recorders

Comment: @SteveMatthews-- The above comment should be made an answer.

Comment: I seem to recall a case where a flight recorder was actually stuck prior to an accident, recording nothing until a midair collision jarred it loose. So it was able to record the aftermath. I'll have to see if I can find that.

Comment: It was the [Zagreb midair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_Zagreb_mid-air_collision). I can't find anything in that article about it, but a book I have says, "The cockpit voice recorder on the Yugoslav aircraft had not been working properly but the impact jolted it into action." (Air Disasters, Stanley Stewart, p. 142)

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comment above, there is lot of aviation accidents with unrecovered flight recorders. List from wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unrecovered_flight_recorders

Comment: Unrecovered is not the same thing as failed.

Comment: How do you know the recorder failed if it wasn't recovered? 